# Почему push выдает ошибку Cannot read property 'push' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

```js
let data = [];
for(let i = 2; i <= 15; i++){
    data[i].push(['test']);
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: `data = []` => `data[i] === undefined` => `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` Л-логика

Comment: push не создаёт `data[i]`, он добавляет в уже существующий объект. Хотите создать - `data[i] = ['test'];`

Comment: @InDevX так `data` же массив, а почему тогда в php подобный код работает?

Comment: @Squeli47 push - метод массива. data - массив. А data[i] на том этапе, в котором вы обращаетесь к нему ?

Comment: @Squeli47 приведите пример на php, раз утверждаете что там работает (нет, там тоже не работает, а верней сказать криво работает).

Comment: _а почему тогда в php подобный код работает?_ - потому что это работает в php, а здесь код на javascript. Это разные языки

Answer (score 1):

`data` массив, но вы ведь делаете `push` не в `data`, а в `data[i]`, а там  после создания `data` ничего ещё нет.

В некоторых языках поддерживается так называемое «автооживление» ([autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification)) — если вы пытаетесь работать с переменной как с массивом или объектом, но там ничего нет, массив или объект создаются автоматически. Но в JS такого нет, вы должны сначала создать массив в `data[i]`, а потом уже добавлять в него элементы при помощи `push()`.